# Leaping shot op in Online mode?

Tags: dragon-age-inquisition

So i am playing in offline mode for some time i nearly finished everything and i am currently sitting at level 23. I must say i found some pretty op combinations related to ranged class. With leaping shot - skill which makes you jump backwards and shoot multiple projectiles + passive skill that lowers cooldown on each crit + very highly crit based equipment i managed to solo (Like with 1 character) strongest of 10 dragons under 30 seconds.

Now i know it may be normal for level that high but i fought the first dragon for like 5-10 minutes and thought it was an epic battle. Spamming leaping shot 15 times in 30 seconds(since no cooldown and leaping shot is really cheap on energy) and killing dragon this way really does seem op to me.

The leaping shot really is a nuke with this build. My question is, how does this look in the multiplayer version? Also im currently playing at default (second) difficulty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In multiplayer, the maximum level is 20. And it is not easy to find many items as in single player. There is no way you can spam leaping shot as in single player with your build and items like you said.
However, there is a build for Hunter, which is the combination of Leaping Shot and Hook, can deal massive damage. I, myself follow this build and yes, it is great. 
You can have a look [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Qdd_qBrd38Y)

## Further explaination

First, about skills, in multiplayer, we have 2 bow class: Archer and Hunter. They have different skills tree and it is not the same as the skills tree in single player. So you can't build the exactly same way you build in single player. Second, about items, mobs do not drop items. You can only get items from open chest in maps or buy chest with gold or platinum (which you can purchase by dollars). And the chance to have good loots is not high. (Good loots are easier to get by completing weekly challenge/event from Bioware). Third, crafting, it is not as diverse as in single player

Comment: Excuse me but i dont quite understand. what is the thing that prevents me from going the same build i use in single player?'And it is not easy to find many items as in single player.' By this you meant that the drop is lower or that you simply cant find/craft the items from singleplayer?

Comment: @BorisBucek, first, about skills, in multiplayer, we have 2 bow class: Archer and Hunter. They have different skills tree and it is not the same as the skills tree in single player. So you can't build the exactly same way you build in single player. Second, about items, mobs do not drop items. You can only get items from open chest in maps or buy chest with gold or platinum (which you can purchase by dollars). And the chance to have good loots is not high. (Good loots are easier to get by completing weekly challenge/event from Bioware). Third, crafting, it is not as diverse as in single player

Comment: @HienTran Honestly, your comment sounds like a better answer than your answer. I think you should edit your answer to incorporate pieces of your comment, like why it's impossible to spam leaping shot.